# How to open PDF file in my Blackberry application?

Tags: pdf, blackberry

I am creating blackberry application to view PDF files in my application. I have couple of PDF files in my application bundle. I want to read these PDF files in blackberry. anyone have idea how to load this PDF file to read ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No functionality for reading PDF files exists in the BlackBerry APIs.  You'll have to roll this functionality yourself, which sounds like the overall purpose of your application anyways.

Comment: Thanks Fostah. So i am thinking that to view PDF file in My application i will have to write my own PDF render library? Am i correct?

Is there any way i can launch any PDF reader application to read the PDF files on Blackberry device?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but I would check around for some open-source Java libraries for reading PDF files.  These could easily be ported to the BlackBerry for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that loading google viewer inside your Browserfield, that will do the trick! =D!

```
public ScrLoad()
{     
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/appiphone/android/elnorte.pdf";                
    add(new BrowserField(url));        
}
```

Google Docs Viewer http://docs.google.com/gview